# How to install Twilio on VS12?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

While installing Twilio on Visual Studio 2012, I'm getting an error:

```
'Twilio' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this [nuget](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManager) .
And, have you tried this [Twilio ADO.NET Provider](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.TwilioADONETProvider) ?